# Gmail API PubSub Push Endpoint is triggered twice

Tags: gmail-api

We have integrated Gmail API into our app to get the email inbox updates of Gmail accounts. We have used [Gmail watch API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch) to start listening to the updates of the Gmail inbox of a user. We have added a subscription and mentioned the endpoint of our app, Topic-Subscription details screenshot attached below, where we are ready to receive inbox updates.

But there are some Gmail accounts, whenever an email is received on those accounts then our "**push endpoint**" is triggered twice instead of once. That's causing a problem within our app.

Can you please explain that is it possible that a **push endpoint** can be triggered multiple times, on a single email received at the Gmail inbox?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google PubSub / Gmail Webhook: Consistently Receiving Multiple POST Requests From PubSub When Sending An Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619495/google-pubsub-gmail-webhook-consistently-receiving-multiple-post-requests-fro)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the question that you have shared above states that the push endpoint is triggered twice with different historyId, in our case the historyId remains the same

Comment: Additionally we are already ignoring the "draft" label.

Comment: Is this only reproducible with certain accounts? If it can be reproduced with any account, can you provide a minimal reproducible sample? Otherwise, I'd suggest you to contact Workspace support https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213 in order to get assistance.

Comment: @SaadAhmed any updates on this issue? Did you manage to solve it and if yes can you please let us know how (I'm experiencing same issue)?

Comment: @NikolaS . I have handled this problem by handling duplicate email trigged

I have solved this problem by logging each webhook payload into the databse then write cron job for processing the request.

Comment: @SaadAhmed so if I understood you correctly you've let cron job do the handling logic for received Pub/Sub's push notification and process webhook's payload content?

Comment: @NikolaS yes exactly.. its based on history id because they same history id on multiple messages

Comment: Can you please post your solution/explanation of solution in more details as answer to your original question?

Comment: @SaadAhmed anything as answer to your OP? :)